# C++: Timeout for an external application call

Tags: c++, timeout, external, boost-thread

For a c++ program I'm working on, I have to call an external application to do some operations. I can't modify the application. This operations may take too much time so I have to add a timeout. I tried using system() and boost threads

```
int main() 
{
  [...]

  boost::thread t(function1);
  t.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

  [...]

  return 0;
}

void function1()
{
  system("external application");
}
```

but when I return to the main 10 seconds later, the external application is still running in background.
Using exec() instead of system() nothing works because I "lose" the main. What can I do?
I'm on Linux.

Comment: What would you want to happen? Kill the process if the timeout expires?

Comment: I want to stop the external application because it's very "expensive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) instead of `system` (which internally uses these syscalls). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) which explains the *tricky* details.

You could want to use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) in the child. Or in the parent [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) the child (first with `SIGTERM`, then with `SIGKILL`) on timeout.

You may want the child to make its own process group using [setpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) or `setpgrp`, then kill the entire process group with [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html). This would kill both the child and any command it has started (unless these create there own process groups themselves).

You could handle the `SIGCHLD` signal (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). `SIGCHLD` would notably be sent when the child process terminates.

Comment: This means there's no way to kill a thread (in this case after timed_join), right?

Comment: No, because you have to kill the child process.

Comment: I'm trying using fork(): there is another problem. The external application I'm calling with exec (minizinc) creates another process (mzn2fzn). When my program runs kill(pid, SIGTERM) or kill(pid, SIGKILL) I kill only minizinc: mzn2fzn is still alive.

Comment: Then consider using process groups, as I updated in my answer (which you could upvote or accept if it fits).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) you first have to [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) a new process with does the actual `exec`. Then after the timeout you can simply [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) the child process. (And for the last you might want to read about [signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).)